# the django template and combine {{ }}

Tags: python, django, templates

I start with django, and I have a little problem.

Well, I have a tuple (top)  and I wanted to display an element of it  according to another template value (date, which is a datetime type).

So, I did that :

```
{{top.date.day}}
```

Well it doesn't work, so I tried it :

```
{{ top.{{date.day}} }}
```

And it didn't work neither.

So what is the good way to do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `{% with %}` tag to assign the intermediate value to another context variable first.